# Issue with height for outside container/content images

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm modifying a Wordpress theme and I'm having some trouble positioning the outside container images that provide the border for the middle section of content. The problem is that the background images are not extending with the content, instead it stops at the bottom of the browser screen.  The site is located here: http://www.richmindonline.com/test

I've never structured background images in this way before, so I apologize for my being naive to this issue.

Here's the CSS id's for the background image structure:

```
 #main {border:1px solid blue; width:900px; display:block; margin:0px auto;}

#container {
        width: 600px;
    float:left;
    border:0px solid red;
}

#content-before {
    border:0px solid yellow;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:150px;
    left:185px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:20px; 
    height:auto;
    background:url('/test/wp-content/themes/basic/assets/images/main-boxed-light.png') 0px 0px repeat-y;

}


#content {
width:590px;
    border:0px solid green;
    }


#primary {
float:right;
overflow: hidden;
width: 250px;
    border:1px solid brown;
}


#content-after {
    border:0px solid yellow;
    content:"";
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:150px;
    left:1145px;
    bottom:0px; 
    width:20px; 
    height:auto;
    background:url('/test/wp-content/themes/basic/assets/images/main-boxed-light.png') -20px 0px repeat-y;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

Here is my index.php HTML div structure:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">

  <div id="content-before"></div><!-- #content-before-->
         <div id="content">




             <?php /* Top post navigation */ ?>
             <?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
                <div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
                   <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                   <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                </div><!-- #nav-above --><?php } ?>




             <?php /* The Loop — with comments! */ ?>
             <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
             <?php /* Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() */ ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" 
                    <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <?php /* an h2 title */ ?>
                <h2 class="entry-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'your-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h2> 

                     <?php /* Microformatted, translatable post meta */ ?>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
                    <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_link( false, $authordata->ID, $authordata->user_nicename ); ?>" title="<?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'your-theme' ), $authordata->display_name ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></span>
                    <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
                    <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-entry-date">
                          <?php _e('Published ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
                    <span class="entry-date"><abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></abbr></span>
                          <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t" ) ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-meta --> 

                          <?php /* The entry content */ ?>

                                 <div class="entry-content">
                                    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )  ); ?>
                                    <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'your-theme' ) . '&after=</div>');?>                                    </div><!-- .entry-content --> 

                                    <?php /* Microformatted category and tag links along with a comments link */ ?>

                <div class="entry-utility">
                    <span class="cat-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links">
                        <?php _e( 'Posted in ', 'your-theme' ); ?></span><?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
                    </span>                        

                    <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>

                        <?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n" ) ?>
                    <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ) ) ?></span>                

                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n" ) ?>
                </div><!-- #entry-utility -->


            </div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> --> <?php /* Close up the post div and then end the loop with endwhile */ ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>

         <?php /* Bottom post navigation */ ?>
         <?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
                <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( '<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Older posts', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
                <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme' )) ?></div>
            </div><!-- #nav-below --><?php } ?>

         </div><!-- #content --> 

      <div id="content-after"></div>

    </div><!-- #container -->



     <div id="primary" class="widget-area">
    </div><!-- #primary .widget-area -->



<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div style="clear:both"></div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with background images; the issue is because you're not `clearing the floats` on your `<div id="content">` container. This is breaking the page, and thussly, the next positioned object is where the borders stop going down. They are, respectively, `content before` and `content after` for all intents and purposes. Try placing a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the closing `</div>` tag for the aforementioned `<div id="content">` container.

Comment: My bad brother - fat fingers find the return key all too often.

Comment: I tried clearning the floats, but nothing happened. I also tried removing the `bottom:0px` style, but that just made the image disappear. Any other ideas?

Comment: It might not be the right place for the clear of the float, but I'm 100% sure it's a floating issue. Do you want to know how I'm certain? You have a container named `<div id="main">`, if you inspect this container with something like Fire Bug, or Web Inspector, you can see that the content is not being constrained within the div. Instead, rather, something is floated out there and is not cleared, and is causing the layout to break. This is the root of the evil, I would suggest moving the `<div style="clear"></div>` around until you fix the layout issue.

Comment: If after successfully clearing the float and restoring order to your page layout you are still having issues, then we can discuss what's going on at that point. But this is the first hurdle you must tackle.

Answer (score 1):

The min-height value of 100% that you are using to try to stretch the outer columns to the full length of the page isn't working because it returns the browser window height.

Perhaps posting the code for your template file so we can easily see your div structure would help in providing a resolution.

Comment: Adam, thanks for your wanting to take a look.  I have posted the index.php file for your viewing.

Comment: I can see you have now changed the theme to something different so I won't invest more time going through the issues with your template file, but as a general comment its better to start with something basic and then build up the elements rather than work with a complex template file and try to modify it to suit what you require as you will find there are lots of additional elements that not only bloat your code but also can interfere with modifications you try to make. A good starting point would be a basic template structure like Amber Weinberg's Hijinks theme - http://goo.gl/CC2ZJ.